# why does gensim summarize() return blank sometimes?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I'm beginner at nlp and I'm using gensim for the first time.
I noticed that some text it returns a blank summary. For example:

```
from gensim.summarization import summarize
text ="The continued digitization of most every sector of society and industry means that an ever-growing volume of data will continue to be generated. The ability to gain insights from these vast datasets is one key to addressing an enormous array of issues — from identifying and treating diseases more effectively, to fighting cyber criminals, to helping organizations operate more effectively to boost the bottom line."
summarize(text, 0.6)
```

returns:
`''`

When I have equivalent sized paragraphs in other instances it returns a summary, so I know it's not that my ratio is too small. Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Which gensim version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of the answer I'll assume Gensim version 3.8.3 - this is the latest version that (currently) supports summarization, since there are no API stubs in version 4 anymore.

Specifically, when looking at the reference for [`summarize()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/summarization/summariser.html#gensim.summarization.summarizer.summarize), we can read the following:

> Get a summarized version of the given text.
> The output summary will consist of the most **representative sentences** and will be returned as a string, divided by newlines.

The highlighted part also explains why your output is empty: Gensim employs an extractive summarizer, which can only choose different *sentences*, not *sentence parts*. Therefore, either the entire sentence is selected (resulting in no "summarization"), or return the empty answer. Fixing this problem is also not trivial, and I think you have only one of two (sub-optimal) choices:

- Employ an abstractive summarizer. Compared to extractive summarization, abstractive models can actually do what humans usually "expect" from a system, namely re-wording and selection of phrases from a sentence to form a shorter output, without relying on the selection of sentences. However, such models are usually quite compute-intensive, and there is no such model available through Gensim (AFAIK).
- Pre-chunk your text. If you can achieve a reasonable segmentation of your input sentence into several chunks of text, these can be a stand-in for "multiple sentences", and therefore would allow you to have an approximate summary, even though it probably isn't very good.

Comment: Thank you so much @dennlinger that helps me understand more how gensim works and what to expect

Answer (score 2):

Note that the reason the prior Gensim summarization code was removed as of `gensim-4.0.0` was that that code was neither very good, nor very adaptable, nor were there any active project contributors able to maintain/improve the code.

So you shouldn't expect very much from it. Of course, you could continue to use it, if it were good enough for your purposes, by installing the older Gensim or simply lifting its source code into another compatibly-licensed project.

You've specifically hit one of the (many) ways it wasn't very good: the best that its kind of "extractive summarization" style can do is pick some smaller count of existing sentences that it deduces are most-representative of the text as a whole.

But with only 2 sentences, its crude word-counting algorithm essentially has no way to decide which of the 2 is better. Essentially, there's no third sentence to break the tie. Hence, per its documentation, with no idea of a smaller subset of sentences to answer, it answers nothing.

Extractive summarization is most likely to give good results on longer texts which have already been written in a clear, expository style - where the author has already used a mix of introductory, deeper-explanation, and summary sentences. Then, some sentences will appear, to the algorithm, to be "most similar" via word counts to the largest number of other sentences, and thus good picks for summaries or key/repeated points.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. That's very helpful. Do you have any recommendations on a python library that might do summarizations for smaller paragraphs better than gensim. I'm exploring NLP and I'd like to build something to help summarize shorter paragraphs?

Comment: I can't recommend any offhand. I know deeper-neural-network langauge-transformer models, which are quite a bit more involved to train & use, are often be used to generate text, often as completion of a prompt or paraphrasing of longer output – but sometimes the text will seem off or nonsensical to full human language understanding. For example, here's an article claiming abstractive-summarization breakthroughs with the BERT model – https://towardsdatascience.com/summarization-has-gotten-commoditized-thanks-to-bert-9bb73f2d6922 – though I can't vouch for any of its claims/recommendations.